# Column titles of dataframes very small in Spyder since update

Tags: spyder

I have been using Spyder for Python and since an update the column titles of a dataframe in the variable explorer are quite small and I don't know how to change that. Before the update the size was good.

Here is a screenshot
[image]

Any idea how I can change that?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem should be fixed i our latest version available in Anaconda (5.1.5). Please update to it and let me know if that solves the problem for you.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba: Thanks for your answer Carlos. Wenn I try to update Spyder I get the message "Spyder is up to date"

Comment: So what's your current Spyder version?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba: 5.1.5. In previous Spyder versions I did not have this problem but since the update the this version this problem occurs

Comment: That's weird. Are you using a high resolution screen?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba: I played a little bit with my screen resolution and now - even after switchting back to the original resolution - the fonts in the variable explorer are quite large which also does not look good. I think there are some scaling issues with the new version of Spyder because before the update to the new version, everything was working fine, no matter which screen I was using.

Comment: I disabled the option "Enable auto high DPI scaling" in the preferences menu and now it looks quite good. Thank you for the hint Carlos with the high resolution screen

Comment: @CarlosCordoba It still occurs in latest Spyder version. I have switched to "Normal" DPI scaling. Still it is happening.

Comment: @SoumyaBoral, you need to restart Spyder for those changes to take effect.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Its still the same.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what could be happening in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the option "Enable auto high DPI scaling" as [hinted at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70362382/column-titles-of-dataframes-very-small-in-spyder-since-update/71434345#comment124421170_70362382) by [Carlos Cordoba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438386/carlos-cordoba):

> That's weird. Are you using a high resolution screen?

and [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70362382/column-titles-of-dataframes-very-small-in-spyder-since-update/71434345#comment124488953_70362382) by [PeterBe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7133942/peterbe):

> I disabled the option "Enable auto high DPI scaling" in the preferences menu and now it looks quite good. Thank you for the hint Carlos with the high resolution screen

in the comments worked for me.