# Spyder: spyder variable explorer to auto-adjust the column header

Tags: spyder

I have installed spyder via Anaconda and when I viewed the dataframe in the variable explorer, the column headers are squashed / too narrow. I cannot view the column headers properly. Please see screenshot below.

How can I make spyder auto-adjust the height?

[image]

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) See the comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70362382/column-titles-of-dataframes-very-small-in-spyder-since-update) for the solution.

Comment: Thanks @CarlosCordoba. I tried disable "Enable auto high DPI scaling" settings. Didn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. That's the only thing we know it could fix this.

Comment: i guess i will have to wait for another batch of update :)

Answer (score 0):

I just updated to Spyder 5.1.5 and this problem is still there, and "Enable auto high DPI scaling" solution does not work. Running Windows 10. This is a pretty annoying bug, and seems to be persistent since Spyder 3.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31710746)